# Proper structure for controllers and views. yii2

Tags: yii2

I have MapsController that uses data from Colonias model (MapsController returns a bunch of vars needed for Maps view to work). Then I render Maps view.

I also have ChartsController that uses data from Colonias model, too. It returns vars needed for Charts view to work.

I want to render Charts view inside Maps view. In order to do it I'd have to call ChartsController action from MapsController.

```
Yii::$app->runAction('ChartsController/Topten');
```

So that MapsController would be able to return vars for Maps view plus Charts view vars. Then it is possible to render Charts inside Maps.

But calling actions from other controllers is NOT a GOOD PRACTICE. Both Maps and Charts use data from Colonias model (and some other models). Both use the same view (Charts inside Maps). But they have different Controller.

I decided to have two different controllers because data is extracted and treated differently although it is from the same model.

I have read articles about GOOD PRACTICE but nothing refers to this...

How would you do it??? Would you use only One controller for everything??? Is it correct/Incorrect to have a large controller(joining Maps and Charts controller)? What it is the best way to do it in order to GOOD PRACTICE? Thanks

Comment: You can use [widgets](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-widgets#creating-widgets) for this case

Comment: you can use widgets or one way could be using `yii\rest\Controller` to act as an API that returns you the data as `json` or any desired supported format, it would return the same vars as your `ChartController/Topten`, and you can use the info according to your needs

Comment: Thank you so much guys I did as widget. It works PERFECTLY